# How to add new custom font icons in ionic2

Tags: ionic2

Im a beginner in using ionic2 and Im having a hard time in adding new custom font icons. Can someone help me? or send a link of a tutorial that I could follow? As of now in researching all I can see are tutorials for ionic 1 using gulp. Is there any other easy way that I could do for ionic2? I already have my generated font icons from icomoon. Thanks! Appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add your icomoon icons following below steps

- Copy your icomoon style.css file to the www/build/css folder.
- Copy the icomoon fonts files (.eot, .svg, .ttf, .woff) to the
  www/build/fonts folder.
- Open the style.css file and edit URL path with correct font path.
  (may be you have to just include ../fonts to match the fonts
  directory). Also use double-quotes instead of single-quotes in the
  url and format.
- Open the index.html file and include

  ```
       <link href="build/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  ```
- Open your HTML file and include the icon at required place as

  ```
        <span class="icon-quill"></span>
  ```

Comment: My files get removed after every build, so I put my files in a separate folder. Don't you have the same problem?

Comment: Yes. Actually you have to copy the files in seperate folder and add gulp task to add it in build folder. I am unable to edit my answer due to some restriction